# Understanding opaque data type

Tags: c, ssl, types

In the TLS 1.0 specification provided the description of types using in there. Here is a piace of that descripiton:

> Single byte entities containing uninterpreted data are of type opaque.

To me, it's not quite clear what uninterpreted data should be treated as. For instance, this is used in the following structure:

```
struct {
  ConnectionEnd          entity;
  BulkCipherAlgorithm    bulk_cipher_algorithm;
  CipherType             cipher_type;
  uint8                  key_size;
  uint8                  key_material_length;
  IsExportable           is_exportable;
  MACAlgorithm           mac_algorithm;
  uint8                  hash_size;
  CompressionMethod      compression_algorithm;
      opaque                 master_secret[48];
      opaque                 client_random[32];
      opaque                 server_random[32];
  } SecurityParameters;
```

May someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're only using `opaque` for documentation purposes, to emphasize that TLS itself does not interpret the data (since its meaning is specific to e.g. the cipher and hash functions used). In practice, you can think of `opaque` as `char`, which is guaranteed to be a single byte.

In a practical implementation containing a `struct` definition like that, you're likely to find

```
typedef char opaque;
```

or

```
#define opaque char
```

somewhere before it.

(`unsigned char`, `uint8_t` (from *<stdint.h>*), and their own `uint8` are some other possibilities, but that's just a minor implementation detail. In practice, those all boil down to either `char` or `unsigned char`. The `#define opaque char` variant appears in */usr/include/rpc/key_prot.h* on my Linux system by the way.)